Is there a way to prevent the third party malleability when using OP_GREATERTHANOREQUAL in multisig?
According to this issue, I noticed if taproot multisig script(using OP_CHECKSIGADD) uses OP_GREATERTHANOREQUAL instead of OP_NUMEQUAL, there's a third party malleability as quoted below.

For any additional signatures provided after the threshold has been reached, a third party can trivially remove those signatures and the transaction is still valid. Miniscript tries to not be third party malleable

I just wonder if there's a way to prevent additional signature from being removed(preferably with implementation of script), or just impossible.
Moreover, I also wonder if there's any other malleability using OP_GREATERTHANOREQUAL instead of OP_NUMEQUAL in multisig script.
